# Do i need to go from shared hosting to vps or a dedicated server?

Tags: vps, shared-hosting, dedicated-hosting, high-traffic

I currently have a website and once i write a new blog post i send out the link to my contacts in my whatsapp groups

since there will be an inrush of requests to the same blog post, will my current shared hosting be sufficient.

how do i know if my shared hosting is performing well enough to serve all those requests.

or do i just go for vps or dedicated server due to the single fact that there will be multiple requests from different ip's to load the same blog post at the same time

Comment: Yes. Unless I'm wrong. In which case, no. But based on the information given, I can give you a definite maybe.

Comment: @Cyrax We really don't have enough information to be able to advise you, but it's never a bad thing to start off with something that can be scaled up like a VPS. Dedicated servers come in different configurations and specs, so it's impossible to comment on those, but are often thought to be the next step after a VPS. Using control panels (like cPanel), will help in migrating upwards. I'd suggest talking with your hosting provider for available options and a plan to deal with increased traffic.